# Script runs when I type it into a terminal, but not when I run it from a .sh file

Tags: scripts, docky

I wanted to run this at start-up because I like to play around with multiple DEs. When I run this script from a file it won't run Docky.

I have already changed the file permissions so that it is allowed to run as a program.

When I type exactly this into gnome-terminal it will run Docky if I am logged into gnome-classic. I wanted to run this script at startup so that Docky wouldn't start in Unity:

```
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION == "gnome-classic" ] ; then docky ; fi
```

Any suggestions?
I tried writing something like Firefox in the same file and it will start Firefox.
So when I run the following script from a file...

```
cd /home/user/Desktop
mkdir ITRAN
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION == "gnome-classic" ] ; then docky ; fi
```

It makes a new file on my desktop but won't run Docky even though if I simply copy the same code into a terminal window it runs...

With geirha's help, I changed the script.  However, now docky launches no matter what DE I run, Unity or gnome-classic.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION = "gnome-classic" ]; then
   docky
fi
```

I've also tried

```
$DESKTOP_SESSION = "gnome-classic"
$DESKTOP_SESSION = gnome-classic
"$DESKTOP_SESSION" = gnome-classic
"$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "gnome-classic"
```

to rule out the possibility that I had that part wrong.

Comment: What file are you using to run the script, .profile, .bashrc, etc....?

Comment: A .sh file I created in my home folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[` command does not have a `==` operator. Bash allows it, but dash will cringe. The correct operator to use is `=`. The script you posted in your question does not have a shebang, so it likely gets run by `sh`. So:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p "$HOME/Desktop/ITRAN"
if [ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = gnome-classic ]; then
    docky
fi
```

Anyway, if it fails, you'll likely find the error messages in `~/.xsession-errors`, so look in there for clues.

Comment: Now it runs no matter what DE I run...

Comment: @utsuro, Well, it only runs docky if `DESKTOP_SESSION` contains `gnome-classic`, so I'd look into two things. 1. Check that you don't have any other scripts that run docky (like a previous attempt at this script). 2. Check that DESKTOP_SESSION actually gets set to different values for different DEs. (Using the default session (with unity) on my 12.04 install, DESKTOP_SESSION is set to `ubuntu` here)

Comment: Yeah, I tested it first in gnome-classic and it launched and then, Docky made an entry in the start-up applications list -____- I though I disabled that...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Moreover, make sure your script is executable:

```
chmod a+x path/to/your/script.sh
```

Comment: In my post I said I had changed the permission